# windows run docker with --network=host and access with 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I have windows 10 pro and I'm trying to run a docker with network mode host.

my issue is that I can't run a docker and access it using the host ip not 127.0.0.1 and not the ip (in linux it works differently).

looks like the hyper v has it's own network that not accessible using the host ip

```
docker run -d --network=host nginx
```

output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
8edd86bf292b        nginx                                             "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                        happy_curie
```

so there is no ports as expected but and no errors.
When I'm trying to open the browser using 127.0.0.1 I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` 
if I set ports to instead of network mode host it is working

```
docker run -d -p 80:80   nginx
```

Hyper v  Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . .
```

Remarks:

- changing in the hyper v virtual switch manager the network to be external - not helping

  - firewall is disabled

any idea how to work with network mode host in windows?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately *host* networking is [not available](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#prerequisites) for *Docker for Windows* and [neither is](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/#prerequisites) *macvlan* networking. If you are not stuck on *Hyper-V*, consider using [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/) on Windows.

Quoted from: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#prerequisites

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

Also see the following related issues on GitHub:

1. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1644
2. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/937
3. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/543
4. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2716

Comment: Can't user Docker Toolbox as its not compatible with Docker for Windows and Mac

Comment: Incredible, this still is an issue on Windows...

Comment: damn windows... lol

Comment: Omg, waste 4 hours to try to do it. Thanks, man. You save me another few hours of tries...

Comment: When you say _Docker for Windows_, are you referring to both Windows Containers and **Linux Containers** (running inside **WSL2**)?

Comment: @LuisÁngelBerríos Yes. Host networking only works on Linux hosts. Docker Desktop with the WSL2 backend using Linux containers still qualifies as a Windows host. If you want host networking, you can uninstall Docker Desktop, and install Docker Engine natively inside WSL2.